# Validation Accuracy doesnt improve at all from the beggining

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am trying to classify the severity of COVID XRay using 426 256x256 xray images and 4 classes present. However the validation accuracy doesnt improve at all. The validation loss also barely decreases from the start

This is the model I am using

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Dropout,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(4,4),input_shape=image_shape,activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(6,6),input_shape=image_shape,activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu")) 
model.add(Dense(16,activation="relu")) 
model.add(Dense(4,activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"])
```

These are the outputs I get

```
epochs = 20
batch_size = 8
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
          epochs=epochs, 
          batch_size=batch_size
          )


Epoch 1/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 143ms/step - loss: 0.1776 - accuracy: 0.9528 - val_loss: 3.7355 - val_accuracy: 0.2717
Epoch 2/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.1152 - accuracy: 0.9481 - val_loss: 4.0038 - val_accuracy: 0.2283
Epoch 3/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0875 - accuracy: 0.9858 - val_loss: 4.1756 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 4/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0521 - accuracy: 0.9906 - val_loss: 4.1034 - val_accuracy: 0.2717
Epoch 5/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0496 - accuracy: 0.9858 - val_loss: 4.8433 - val_accuracy: 0.3152
Epoch 6/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0170 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 5.6027 - val_accuracy: 0.3043
Epoch 7/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.2307 - accuracy: 0.9245 - val_loss: 4.2759 - val_accuracy: 0.3152
Epoch 8/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.6493 - accuracy: 0.7830 - val_loss: 3.8390 - val_accuracy: 0.3478
Epoch 9/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.2563 - accuracy: 0.9009 - val_loss: 5.0250 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 10/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0286 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.6475 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 11/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0097 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.2198 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 12/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0037 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.7914 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 13/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0048 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.4341 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 14/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0044 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.6364 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 15/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 143ms/step - loss: 0.0019 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.8504 - val_accuracy: 0.2391
Epoch 16/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 143ms/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.9604 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 17/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 149ms/step - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 6.0851 - val_accuracy: 0.2717
Epoch 18/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0134 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 4.9783 - val_accuracy: 0.2717
Epoch 19/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 141ms/step - loss: 0.0068 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.7421 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 20/20
27/27 [==============================] - 4s 142ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.8480 - val_accuracy: 0.2283
```

Any tips on how i can solve this or If i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like classical overfitting to me. Your training accuracy reaches 100%, whereas test accuracy decays. In this case, I would first look at the data. Here are some questions I would investigate: Do you shuffle the data? Is your validation set representative of the rest of the dataset? How big is your validation set? (Maybe it consists of outliers?) Do you treat your training set differently at some point in preprocessing than your validation set? You might also try `BatchNorm` instead of dropout, as I can imagine it might work better than dropout for X-Rays.

Comment: Shuffling is done. Validation is representative of the whole set roughly.
I tried data augmentation on Train set but that just causes the training loss to stagnate and the training accuracy also stagnates around 0.4 from epoch 1. Same thing with val loss and accuracy. This code shown above is without augmentation. 

Why is augmentation leading to low training accuracy??

Comment: Augmentation is supposed to make the model more robust toward perturbations in the inputs, if you overdo it, it can make the downstream task very hard and potentially too hard to solve. Beyond that, your code above does not show any data and data augmentation so its impossible to say it more specifically.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info